# How to convert MOngoDB.BsonDocumnet to list of collection in c#?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have MongoDB.BsonDocument, i want to convert that BsonDocument to List of collection, how can i do this one, i paste my sample code below...

```
try
{
    var server = MongoServer.Create("localhost:27017");
    var db = server.GetDatabase(DATABASE);
    var riskdata = db.GetCollection("TABLESAMPLE");
    var query = Query.EQ("Name", null);
    var results = riskdata.Find(query);
    gridsample.ItemsSource = results;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

but above code not working for me...."_id" only binding to grid, remaining fields are not coming.

Comment: What data do you have in that table? Show us.

Comment: in Table i have 3 columns, Name Sender Target> In grid also i have sample columns.when i retrieve the document from Mongo table and i need to bind to that collection to grid.@ Sergei Tulentsev

Comment: previously for binding table data to grid, i am using foreach like..    http://pastebin.com/BKYfn58x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your grid does not understand `BsonDocument`.

You need to take a look at serializing those [BSON documents into classes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial).

It will look something like this:

```
class MyDocument { 
    public string name { get; set; }

    public int a { get; set; }

    public int b { get; set; }
}
```

Then you change your find to return these things

```
IEnumerable<MyDocument> results = riskdata.FindAs<MyDocument>(query).ToList();
gridsample.ItemsSource = results;
```

Now you will have a class with properties that your grid can read.

Comment: Hi Gates VP, i tried with above code i got error like "Error The non-generic method 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>.Find(MongoDB.Driver.IMongoQuery)' cannot be used with type argument"

Comment: @GatesVP: 1. No need to use `BsonElement` attribute when you don't whant use different field name than property name. 2. To tell driver automatically deserialize documents to particular type need to use `FindAs<MyTypeHere>` instead of `Find`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, absolutely right, I wrote this from my non-Windows computer, so I wasn't able to double-check the syntax. Fixed the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

you can bind BsonDocument with any structure by convert BsonBocument to Data table without declare class

```
    public DataTable GetDataTableFromMongoCursor(MongoCursor cursor)
    {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.Count() > 0)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable(cursor.ToString());
            foreach (BsonDocument doc in cursor)
            {

                foreach (BsonElement elm in doc.Elements)
                {
                    if(!dt.Columns.Contains(elm.Name))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(elm.Name));
                    }

                }
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (BsonElement elm in doc.Elements)
                {
                    dr[elm.Name] = elm.Value;

                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dt;

        }
         return null;
    }
```